# How to setup IDE for better development of React Native

Tags: visual-studio-code, react-native, atom-editor, react-native-ios

I'm new to react native and I came from Android background. I have used to work on Android Studio. Which provides lot of features including `autocompletion`, `suggestions`, `code correction` etc.

Now, I just started React native development on `vscode`, there is no reason for it's selection. but here in `vscode` I need to explicitly write `import statements` and then  I need to also write the code.

Kindly answer below questions,

**1> The problem I'm facing here Is, why import statements are not generating by itself as in case of android studio ?**

**2> Which IDE is best ?**

**3> how to configure IDE for better development ?**

**4> Any good official tutorial for IDE selection for react native ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1> The problem I'm facing here Is, why import statements are not generating by itself as in case of android studio ?**  --- >> I wouldnt prefer android studio as that just suits best for android / kotlindevelopment.And react native also has IOS part. But the coding part is mostly in JS, so VScode would be best. And for snippets, you can add extension

> React-Native/React/Redux snippets for es6/es7

Its good. and others like auto closing tags etc

**2> Which IDE is best ?** VS code coz it has such stability, and great extensions

**3> how to configure IDE for better development ?** Extensions like, color bracket, ESlint/Pretty , The above extension which i mentioned should be enough.Thats it pretty much.

4> Any good official tutorial for IDE selection for react native ?  Any tutorial first teaches you proper setup and tells what all things to be downloaded. you can check --- [check this](https://medium.com/react-native-training/vscode-for-react-native-526ec4a368ce) ,. main thing is you hsould be comfortable.thats it.

Enjoy coding. Hope it helps. feel free for doubts

Comment: i asked this because so many people blog preffered Atom over Vscode without proper explanation. So i asked this here.

Comment: is this plugin needed 'React Native Tools'. upto what extent i can avoid this plugin. can you tell based on your experience.

Comment: i dont use much of code snippets, but ive not used react native tools, it always better go for rn docs and checkfor latest code. thats how i do , so that error prone is less

Comment: glad it helped you :D